# Not able to retrieve parent tag using BeautifulSoup and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

From an Instagram page i am trying to retrieve parent element of a img tag. But i am getting error as:

```
AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

Below is my simple code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url=urlopen("https://www.instagram.com/people")
html=url.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
elem=soup.find('img',{'id':'pImage_0'}).parent
print((elem))
```

Can someone please tell me on why i am not able to retrieve parent tag or what is the mistake i am doing? I am able to retrieve the content of img tag though(by removing parent from code.):

```
<img alt="Congrats!  #CassadeePope is engaged to #AllTimeLow drummer    #RianDawson! Get all of the sweet details in our bio link! | #Repost @cassadeepope: WE'RE ENGAGED ❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤" class="_icyx7" data-reactid="43" id="pImage_0" src="https://instagram.fdel1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/16465038_376289889403372_5052986327474110464_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTQ0NzUzMjA0NDk1NTIzNDkzNA%3D%3D.2" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This page is loaded by JavaScript and the img tag is generated by JS, and requests only return the HTML code, so, you can not retrieve the HTML code and the

```
soup.find('img',{'id':'pImage_0'})
```

will return `None`

Comment: That is not true. `soup.find('img',{'id':'pImage_0'})`  returned the content in img tag

Comment: @Naveen Gabriel print it out and post in the question